# Правильно ли поставлены запятые в моем тексте?

Tags: пунктуация

В связи с запросом о необходимости обследования МКД  на территории н.п. ...... с целью выявления и дальнейшего устранения обслуживающими организациями снежных массив наледей с крыш домов,  представляющих опасность для жизни и здоровья граждан, комитет по управлению имуществом просит Вас предоставить графики уборки и вывоза снега  в н.п. .....